# Entity Framework OrderBy multiple properties generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, .net-core

I have this project in .NET Core, and we use Entity Framework. I'm trying to create a method for `orderby`, I know you can do it by with multiple properties like this:

```
context.MyObject.OrderBy(x => new
        {
            x.Property1,
            x.Property2,
            x.Property3
        });
```

Without installing `Linq.Dynamic`, I would like to achieve something like that by passing strings, I don't know if with reflection maybe I could do something similar.

```
public IQueryable<T> OrderByMultiple(string[] myProperties) where T : class 
{
    ///some code here
    context.Set<T>.OrderBy(x => new
    {
        ///Get the properties by the strings
        ///"Property1",
        ///"Propety2",
        ///"Property3"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out you can pass an array of strings to the `orderBy`

```
        query.OrderBy(x => new
        {
            propertyList
        });
        return query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

context.MyObject.OrderBy(x => x.propertyA).ThenBy(x=> x.propertyB)